Circular plate buckling and load sharing
There are 2 circular plates with 6m OD and 5.8m ID. One plate is plastic and the other is metal. They are identical geometrically, and only vary by material. They rest on top of each other purely by axial preload of self weight. They are not bolted or bonded together, and have no interlocking features holding them together. When exposed to external pressure (hydrostatic pressure outside and vacuum inside), I calculate the plastic plate to buckle at a relatively low critical pressure. Does the metal plate limit the hoop stress in the plastic plate? Effectively, acting as a vacuum vessel, is there any load sharing (stiffer metal plate carries more load)? I calculate these as separate plates for buckling since they are not bonded together in any way. Is this a correct assessment?

Is this a cylindrical vessel? How do you calculate the critical pressure?

Yes, this is a cylindrical vessel. It’s made up of circular plates stacked on top of one another. The plates are loaded axially by weight of other components to maintain preload. I’ve calculate critical pressure using Roark’s, circular plate with concentric hole under uniform radial compression. Geometry factor K x modulus x thickness/outer radius. Specifically for this question, I’m looking at elastic stability (buckling) due to external pressure only.

The critical pressure from Roark's is probably not for buckling. This design is still hard to for me to imagine. What are the thicknesses of the plates? Are there just 2 plates loaded axially just by sef-weight? Could you add a sketch?

I’ve added a sketch now. It’s not extremely detailed as I’m traveling and using mobile. Thickness of plastic plate is 70mm and thickness of steel is 10mm. Plates are axially loaded by self-weight of many other components, leading to a fairly large axial load. Then, once assembled, they are subject to axial load shown and hydrostatic pressure (labeled as external pressure).
